# Error on site with mathematical operation on ASP .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, math, percentage, operation

I have count and percentage of some things from my databases and show them on site.( with mathematical operation)
But If database be empty , I see this error:

adminContentCount.UserPercentage = (currentMonthUser * 100) / userCount;
this is my service:

```
 CountViewModel adminContetnCount = new CountViewModel()
        {
            
           UserCount = await _userRepository.UserCount(),
       
            CurrentMonthUser = await _userRepository.CurrentMonthUser(),

      
        };
```

and this is my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var adminContentCount = await _siteService.AdminContentCount();
    
        var userCount = adminContentCount.UserCount;
        var currentMonthUser = adminContentCount.CurrentMonthUser;

        return View(adminContentCount);
    }
```

I use it on service and on controller and then will be show On view

How can I check this on my service. I get count of them and percentage from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your error posted here, but I'm assuming it's a divide by 0. Therefore

```
adminContentCount.UserPercentage = userCount == 0 ? 0 : (currentMonthUser * 100) / userCount;
```

Comment: Thank so much .yes it was mean divide by 0 so I see the error:
adminContentCount.UserPercentage = (currentMonthUser * 100) / userCount; this is my service:

so with this if just check user account ? and I had not check currentMonthUser too?

Comment: You don't need to check the other one. Math doesn't let you divide by 0 but you can multiply by it, it would just still be 0. - If you're dividing by it anywhere though, check it there.  =)